# Finding palindrome of sum

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the problem statement:
For a given no. `num`, perform:
1. Add `num` and `reverse(num)`

2. Check whether the `sum` is palindrome or not. Else repeat.

Here is my solution. The program seems to be working for the 3 test cases given but when I am executing this program, for 1 private test case I am getting server time out error. Is my program not efficient?

```
flag=0
iteration=0
num = 195 # sample no. output produced is 9339 which is a palindrome.
while(flag!=1):
    #print("iteration ",iteration)
    num_rev= int(str(num)[::-1]) #finding rev of number
    #print(num_rev)
    total= num+num_rev #adding no and no_rev
    #print(total)
    total_rev= int((str(total))[::-1]) # finding total rev
    iteration=iteration+1
    if total==total_rev: #if equal, printing palindrome
        print("palindrome")
        flag=1
    else:
        num=total #else the new no becomes sum of old num and old_rev
```

Comment: Could you please specify each of the 3 test cases you mentioned? Thank you.

Comment: What is the server's timeout limit set to?

Comment: @clockelliptic 1st is 0. o/p is 0. 2nd is 4 o/p 8. 3rd in 195. o/p is 9339

Comment: @clockelliptic It is hidden. I don't know.

Comment: I wonder if there is a certain expectation for how your code handles single digits? As far as the definition of a palindrome goes, a single digit or single letter does not qualify as a palindrome. In fact, a palindrome must have 3 or more elements. Perhaps your code needs to account for this--I've edited my answer below to account for the definition of a palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by profiling your code for each of your test cases to find out what is taking so long. I suggest using **Jupyter Notebook**'s code profiling magic. Paste your code into a Jupyter Notebook cell and being the cell with `%%prun`. Along with other information, it will return a list of function calls, the number of times each function is called, and the amount of time each function takes to run. Compare the run time of your test cases to your server's timeout limit.

If the problem is not with your code and its evolving complexity as the number increases in size, it may be a problem with your server.

...

Note that a palindrome must contain at least 2 or 3 elements depending on your accepted definition.

Consider that one of your test cases may be venturing into arbitrarily large integers that take an unpredictable amount of time to compute. Consider that this compute time may exceed your server's timeout limit.

Furthermore, consider this modified version of your code that accepts an arbitrarily-defined max iteration depth per seed number. It also accepts an arbitrary seed number and a max seed number. Then returns an ordered list of all non-duplicate seed numbers, their respective palindrome sums, the number of iterations required to find the palindrome, and the approximate time required to perform the search:

```
#flag = 0
iteration = 0
maxiter   = 1000
num       = 0
max_num   = 10000

used_seeds = []
palindromes = []

while num < max_num:
    seed = num

    while(iteration <= maxiter) and len(str(total))>2:
        if num in used_seeds: 
            break

        iteration+=1

        num_reversed   = int(str(num)[::-1])
        total          = num + num_reversed
        total_reversed = int((str(total))[::-1])

        if total == total_reversed:
            used_seeds.append(num)
            palindromes.append( [num, total] )
            break
        else:
            num = total

    num = seed+1
    iteration = 0

palindromes.sort(key=lambda elem: elem[0])
print(palindromes)
```

The results are fascinating, by the way. Hopefully this helps.